# Motd doesn't show up

Tags: osx, motd

I'd like to set a custom motd ("message of the day") on my machine (currently Mac OS X 10.6.5 using Bash with Terminal.app).

In `/etc/` there was no **motd** file so I created one with some sample text. But the message doesn't show up when I restart Terminal. I've tried to `logout` and then `login` but it still doesn't seem to kick in.

If I do `ls -l /etc/motd` I get (if it's any clue):

`-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  30  7 Dec 11:58 /etc/motd`

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Seems I worked it out. My motd not showing up must have been due to the fact that I had touched/added an empty file in my home directory called .hushlogin, which actually supresses any login messages (seems it doesn't just kill motd but any other login messages as well, as I understand it). At any rate, my problem is somehow solved and chances are I forgot to delete that .hushlogin file.

Comment: Feel free to accept your own answer! https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your distribution, the system may create a new motd automatically on each startup. Ubuntu seems to be doing that at least.

Cheers

Comment: Yes, that may be the case with my distro as well (Darwin/BSD). At there is this "Last login: Tue Dec  7 16:10:04 on ttys000" message each time I fire up a new Terminal frame.

Comment: An empty .hushlogin file in your ~ dir will hide any motd and the message I mentioned in my prev. comment above.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on your distribution.

In general you can create `/etc/motd` file and contents will show on login, together with contents from `/etc/motd.dynamic`.

If you create `/etc/update-motd.d` and place scripts there they will populate `/etc/motd.dynamic`.

Some distros modify `/etc/motd.dynamic` in `/etc/init.d/motd`

See details here

https://ownyourbits.com/2017/04/05/customize-your-motd-login-message-in-debian-and-ubuntu/