# How to display welcome message in unix?

Tags: linux, login, motd

How can I display the welcome message "welcome panni" every time I log into unix?

Comment: Please don't keep posting the same question...

Answer (score 49):

Normally, a welcome message can be shown by customizing the `/etc/motd` file (which stands for Message Of The Day).  `/etc/motd` is not a script but a text file which contents are shown before the first prompt of a login session.

You can also add some messages in `/etc/profile` or `/etc/bashrc` scripts using the `echo` or `print` commands (note that the `/etc/bashrc` assumes you are using the bash shell).

Here are examples of commands that can be added to `/etc/profile` file to obtain a result like the one you expected:

```
echo "Welcome ${USER}"
```

or

```
echo "Welcome $(whoami)"
```

OBS1: If the system is correctly configured, the results of the above should be the same, but the ways they work are different: The first one shows the `$USER` environment variable while the second executes the command `whoami`.

OBS2: Note that the `/etc/profile` is ran once per session and only for login shells.  This means that the message will be shown when the user logs in in the console or `rsh`/`ssh` to the machine, but not when he/she simply opens a terminal in an X session, for example.

Comment: Sure.  BTW, adding a standalone script under `/etc/profile.d` directory as goldilocks suggests in his answer may be a better approach than editing `/etc/profile` directly, but this solution really depends on the unix flavor and how recent it is.  In both approaches, using the ${USER} and the $(whoami) to identify the user should work, BTW.

Comment: Good answer.  Might link to [motd (5)](http://man.flashnux.com/en/centos/5/5.5/man5/motd.5.html).

Answer (score 14):

Create a file in `/etc/profile.d` called `greeting.sh` or whatever you like.  It does not need to be executable or contain a shebang.  You need one line:

```
echo "Hello World"
```

You could also use:

```
echo "All Hail the Flying Spaghetti Monster!"
```

Etc.

If you don't want to do this for every user, add it to `~/.profile` or `~/.bash_profile`, whichever works on your system.

Comment: Other monsters are false monsters, undeserving of capitalization!

Comment: `'s/Spagetti/Spaghetti/'`

Answer (score 12):

Befor login

```
/etc/issue
/etc/issue.net
```

After login

```
/etc/motd
```

Answer (score 6):

If you allow access via SSH, you can specify a banner file in /etc/ssh/sshd_config using the Banner directive.

Answer (score 3):

That is called message of the day, or motd in short. It's located under /etc.
Also see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motd_%28Unix%29 and there should be a man page on your unix system, you should have a look with `man motd`.
For your example, simply set it up via
`echo welcome krishna >> /etc/motd` and try another login.

There are also many threads here related to motd details:
[How do I use colors in the MOTD?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/139056/how-do-i-use-colors-in-the-motd)
[Change motd value in UNIX Operating System](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126423/change-motd-value-in-unix-operating-system)
[Motd doesn't show up](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4598/motd-doesnt-show-up)

For more details, what unix flavour do you use, so people can maybe provide some hints for specific configurations related to that specific unix flavour? Or, as your question is tagged with #linux, is it about linux and motd in general? Also, how do you login?

Comment: I don't believe panni wants the "hello krishna" message hard coded for every user, but just for krishna.  Better using the `USER` environment variable or the `whoami` command in the `/etc/profile` script as in my answer.

Comment: Hmmm, maybe it was just a typo and he wants to display "Hare Krishna" to all users logging in, would your solution be able to do that? :p

Comment: Maybe, but this is not what the "welcome" word suggests... (and yes, of course it is...)